Why the following trace function is not working as desired?
let o = {
        x : 1, 
        y : 2, 
        z : 3,
    };

o.sq = function(n){ 
        return n*n; 
   };

function trace(o, m) {  // taken from David Flanagan page-187
 var original = o[m];

 o[m] = function() { 
            console.log(new Date(), "Entering:", m);
            var result = original.apply(this, arguments);
            console.log(new Date(), "Exiting:", m); 
            return result; 
        };
}

trace(o, o.sq);
console.log(o.sq(5));

This gives the output only 25.
Why not the modified function is being executed?
Where I am   wrong?
Expected output:
current date time Entering: method name
current date time Exiting: method name
25

Your trace() function expects a property name as the second argument, not the property value itself. Thus:
trace(o, "sq");

will modify the "sq" property of the object.

Thank you Mr Pointy.  Your reply is an eye opener. Many thanks.
